# Select only the first element 'libro' that don't have the attribute 'paginas'

Tags: xpath

Given the attached xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <biblioteca>
      <libro paginas="100">
        <titulo>Los bandidos de la playa</titulo>
        <autor>Rosario Lopez</autor>
        <isbn>1231-123-123-2233</isbn>
        <precio>123</precio>
        <fechaPublicacion año="1920"/>
      </libro>
      <libro paginas="200">
        <titulo>Indagaciones publicas</titulo>
        <autor sexo="M">Aurora Laspitas</autor>
        <isbn>1231-222-3333-4444</isbn>
        <precio>40</precio>
        <fechaPublicacion año="2000"/>
      </libro>
      <libro>
        <titulo>libro barato</titulo>
        <autor sexo="H">Cipriano Lopez</autor>
        <isbn>1231-2343 32333333</isbn>
        <precio>10</precio>
        <fechaPublicacion año="1978"/>
      </libro>
      <libro>
        <titulo>libro de ayuda</titulo>
        <autor sexo="H">Zacarias Sanchez</autor>
        <isbn>1231-2343 32333333</isbn>
        <precio>10</precio>
        <fechaPublicacion año="1999"/>
      </libro>  
   </biblioteca>
```

I want to select only the first element 'libro' that doesn't have the attribute 'paginas'.
Here is my try that doesn't work:

/biblioteca/libro[not(@paginas)]/../libro[1]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/biblioteca/libro[not(@paginas)][1]
```